# Rails submit multiple file_field form via one submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I've got list of missing documents (`kyc_missing`) that user needs to upload. Next to each item I should display a `Upload` button to attach the file and at the end of the form one `Submit` button to attach the entire form. I don't want to store those files, I have to send each uploaded file to another microservice as a `Base64` string. Here is my code:

```
# displayed table

<%= form_with url: kyc_document_upload_path, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <% kyc_missing.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item %></td>
      <td>
        <%= f.fields_for :files do |ff| %>
          <%= f.file_field :file %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Upload', data: { turbo: false } %>
<% end %>


# profile_controller.rb

class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def kyc_document_upload
    file = FileRead.read(params[:file])
    body = Base64.encode64(file)
    ExternalApi.user.sent_missing_docs(body)
    
    redirect_to profile_path, notice: 'File uploaded'
  end
```

The issue is that instead of collection of files (or array of files, dunno really), always gets the last file under `params[:file]`. How to pass all of the attached files not just the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> <%= f.file_field :file %>

with

> <%= ff.file_field :file %>

Thanks

Comment: Well that's my mistake in copy/paste code. The issue will be the same but I'll get last file under `params[:file][:file]` instead